# Remote SSH not workin outside local network

Tags: ssh

I use the Blink shell on my iPad to connect to Jupyter on my Mac. The connection works perfectly while on the same network, but it either returns "Network is down" or "Connect timeout."

The app has all the permissions required and so does the Mac.

I set the Mac as a host in two ways: using the ip address shown in System Preferences and once from https://www.whatismyip.com/my-ip-information/.

Anyoke know how to make the connection work remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Information is not clear, I'm assuming your Mac sits behind an Internet router (NAT).

You can either set up a port forward (e.g. 60022 -> $mac_ip_address:22) from your internet router to the Mac or put the Mac in DMZ (which is not recommended)

Comment: I apologise, but I am quite new to this. My goal is to run Jupyter on my iPad over ssh from a different network.

Comment: I did set up port forwarding on the router web page but it did not help. What is the command you wrote? Is it for the terminal?